# RSA SHA256 http signature in C#

Tags: c#, http, rsa, signature, sha256

I am trying to implement HTTP signature in an API to connect to the EWP network (Erasmus Without Paper). I have an example with working data and I'm trying to test with that data, but I just cannot get to validate the HTTP signature.

With the `keyId` in the request, I retrieve the public key from another API.

Here's what I've got from the example:

```
Header:
Authorization: Signature keyId="2bc25340265c0331632c2bc7d82cabdf3a6ebba0a8cc6435b401d62dd2c7daea",signature="dlpL2OjVMZi4bqFnVtvc8Z6qqOvdmb6g/P42PQrP6w5+/mxF1S9COx7CkRAMi+6KdH0XGdgT4G0Vi85VVI7vSoYgvVCSgBeyFyfP7HwYROEhd1QgM9VgV001wXvDNJbvTOXh2S+1IAP/8YwIM3RQOg64ZRJEMUEWf91VczjTXC9sElGK4jP0AAbsg727cE/b8LeOH25vl6tzyypDFaCCA3MAgdF2+fNdNG9gr0OKa5ia7Dums1aXKmcqhOaWTiiS7vTYhnwBS7BlQMnrDF6kOtVQomVDB11vfEKvmgkXIXxRvpHMTG6+7F32DCu3imS2wIjJccQSglyFFJ4/qjnNKA==",headers="(request-target) date digest host x-request-id",algorithm="rsa-sha256"
Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2020 14:19:18 GMT
Digest: "SHA-256=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU="
Host: "sga-mobilidadenet.ua.pt"
X-Request-Id: "76092379-75d1-462d-b7b7-af6a87b000bd"

Url used is sga-mobilidadenet.ua.pt/mobilidadenet/ewp/ewpstage/echo?echo=a&echo=b&echo=a
```

The public key i got from the other API is

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA67WEK5VlMUFC0wdLmTV4TyeDwA1U4NV5GvL/x29ujKY0/tWSoqwRPvIyhQ6h2M3MQpaLIb4PQsRzh299KaCNQ799+0HH7KMTZMN5AwoSw4y5RS6ImhlwRm4N4yDoekQgQuXTaPLEfYBURPrTJ8/V2Wb6yW8LgfPknESNglRkprhFKOoWJzlv00rzCO7QZSdXh5LYU0TYOlj+WrfoCM8xODOQqCJsnS7grY7YNtR08qB2fo7UEYXrUw8aoe5ZZZeKv1b5M1+ZDR1aAHZRhMbPyp7JIRxW5fAT/ZDxUHv8lfOksgnF+AXHSGFdvteEbSJHrfOnMiUScBil306/VeSVXQIDAQAB
```

(with spaces and line brakes, but I filtered them out?)

What I need to do in my API, is to check if the signature in the authorization header is correct and if the digest is the correct hash.

The code I use to test is this:

```
private void test()
{
    //(request-target) date digest host x-request-id
    string dataForSign = "(request-target): " + "get /mobilidadenet/ewp/ewpstage/echo?echo=a&echo=b&echo=a" + "\n" ;
    dataForSign += "date: " + "Fri, 30 Oct 2020 14:19:18 GMT" + "\n";
    dataForSign += "digest: " + "SHA-256=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=" + "\n";
    dataForSign += "host: " + "sga-mobilidadenet.ua.pt" + "\n";
    dataForSign += "x-request-id: " + "76092379-75d1-462d-b7b7-af6a87b000bd";
    
    string signature = "dlpL2OjVMZi4bqFnVtvc8Z6qqOvdmb6g/P42PQrP6w5+/mxF1S9COx7CkRAMi+6KdH0XGdgT4G0Vi85VVI7vSoYgvVCSgBeyFyfP7HwYROEhd1QgM9VgV001wXvDNJbvTOXh2S+1IAP/8YwIM3RQOg64ZRJEMUEWf91VczjTXC9sElGK4jP0AAbsg727cE/b8LeOH25vl6tzyypDFaCCA3MAgdF2+fNdNG9gr0OKa5ia7Dums1aXKmcqhOaWTiiS7vTYhnwBS7BlQMnrDF6kOtVQomVDB11vfEKvmgkXIXxRvpHMTG6+7F32DCu3imS2wIjJccQSglyFFJ4/qjnNKA==";
    
    string publicKey =
        "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA67WEK5VlMUFC0wdLmTV4TyeDwA1U4NV5GvL/x29ujKY0/tWSoqwRPvIyhQ6h2M3MQpaLIb4PQsRzh299KaCNQ799+0HH7KMTZMN5AwoSw4y5RS6ImhlwRm4N4yDoekQgQuXTaPLEfYBURPrTJ8/V2Wb6yW8LgfPknESNglRkprhFKOoWJzlv00rzCO7QZSdXh5LYU0TYOlj+WrfoCM8xODOQqCJsnS7grY7YNtR08qB2fo7UEYXrUw8aoe5ZZZeKv1b5M1+ZDR1aAHZRhMbPyp7JIRxW5fAT/ZDxUHv8lfOksgnF+AXHSGFdvteEbSJHrfOnMiUScBil306/VeSVXQIDAQAB</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

    
    byte[] dataForSignAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataForSign);
    byte[] signatureEncoded = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(publicKey);

    var hashData = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(dataForSignAsBytes);

    var result1 = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData(dataForSignAsBytes, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signatureEncoded);
    var result2 = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash(hashData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signatureEncoded);
    Console.WriteLine(result1);
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
}
```

both results are false...

I'm really stuck with this and feel like I'm just a few changes away from the solution, but as long as it's not working, I'm stuck... Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have no experience with HTTP signature or RSA-SHA256...

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same recipe to generate the  signature as the other party?

Comment: Note that the data must be exactly the same on both sides for the signature to match. In your example, the request has capitalised header names, while the data you're trying to verify use lowercase header names. A single different character will completely change the signature, so make sure there's no change whatsoever in the data string. You should follow the whole algorithm for computing the signature - as far as I can tell, EWP uses https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-07#section-2.5 - note that the signature contains the whole HTTP message - contents, _all_ headers etc.

Comment: Yeah, look at what @Luaan is saying, i don't think what you've captured is strictly speaking the entire HTTP payload.

Can you use burp/charles/fiddler and capture raw payloads?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The example I got, is from the online development environment, where test requests can be sent to API's that are online. Mine ins not yet online, so I cannot capture anything yet with. I just used the data I found the test was using and tried to test if I could validate it. I used lowercase header names, as the are used in the authorization header: headers="(request-target) date digest host x-request-id" Doesn't this mean these are the only headers I need to use to create the signing string (dataForSign in my code) ?

Comment: If anyone really wants to put time in this, you can find the registry on https://dev-registry.erasmuswithoutpaper.eu/catalogue-v1.xml. XPath function to find the public key:
```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("r", "https://github.com/erasmus-without-paper/ewp-specs-api-registry/tree/stable-v1");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
var XPathExpr = @"//r:binaries/r:rsa-public-key[@sha-256=""" + keyId + @"""]";
clientPublicKey = root.SelectSingleNode(XPathExpr, namespaceManager).InnerText;
```

Comment: And for example https://dev-registry.erasmuswithoutpaper.eu/manifestValidation?url=https://ewp.demo.usos.edu.pl/ewp/manifest can be used to test, I tested with echo API using HTTT > validate > show results > 6 > Show/hide details > Actual request which was made (#-1)

Comment: lowercase header names are required by the standard EWP uses: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-07#section-2.3